# Configuring IIS smtp with gmail

Tags: iis, smtp, gmail, windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server 2012. I followed following URL for configuring IIS smtp 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/10/26/configuring-outgoing-email-settings-in-sharepoint-with-gmail-smtp.aspx

Now my problem is my email are stuck in queued folder, I feel like as I have 2-step verification in gmail account is getting reject. So I change password in my smtp to application specific password. But still same problem.

So now I wanted to know what can be the problem. Is there any tool from which we can say that smtp of gmail is rejecting email.

Hope somebody can help me over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, actually my network team had block 25 port on our network.